# Android action bar and navigation drawer for a new app

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I am building an android app and I need to know whether to use [action bar sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and  jfeinstein10 [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). 
As for ABS, I know it was build for apps supporting older versions of the OS, but now I can see that the latest support library include the action bar. Is there any reason why I should use ABS now?

As for the sliding menu, I have tried it before google published the new Navigation Drawer, it worked great and I decided to use it. But now I am not sure if I should use the Navigation drawer instead. Is the sliding menu has any advantage over the navigation drawer?

Thanks in advance,

Eitan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for [ActionBarCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) if you are going to make new app. Just have look at [Google I/O 2013 - Android Design for UI Developers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl3-lzlzOJI), these new UI Designs are very well explained and you will come to know about the advantages as well.